# Word Addin/OfficeJS - Detect if Cursor is on Chart Element

Tags: javascript, typescript, ms-word, office-js

I want to be able to check if the document cursor is inside of a Chart element within the MS Word API. Right now I have an application that inserts text, but when I try to insert said text into the title of the Chart, it deletes the chart and replaces it with the Content Control I'm inserting.

Instead of deleting the chart, I want to check if the cursor is inside of the Chart via context. If I'm inside of the Chart in any way, be able to throw a warning message to the user and escape. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Since you can't insert a Content Control into a chart using the user interface, it's not surprising that you can't do it programmatically either. A chart can go inside some content controls, not the other way around.

Comment: That's true, but I'm not wanting to insert it, I want to be able to know the cursor is inside and catch the error. Is there a way to check for this? Or do I just check that it fails?

Comment: If you get the ooxml of the Selection you should be able to check whether that contains a chart?

Comment: @CindyMeister is there a built-in way for Office.js to check the OOXML?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but if you mean is there a property or function like "HasChart" then, no. Otherwise I wouldn't have suggested what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. Like @CindyMeister said you can check the ooxml and inspect it, `range.getOoxml()` will only return something if the cursor is on some xml object that's been inserted into the document.

example.ts

```js
Word.run(async (context: RequestContext) => {
  const range: Range = context.document.getSelection();
  const ooxml: ClientResult<string> = range.getOoxml();
  context.load(range);
  await context.sync();

  const ooxmlVal = ooxml.value;
  if (ooxmlVal) {

    const lowered = ooxmlVal.toLowerCase();
    const isChart = lowered.includes("excel") && lowered.includes("chart");
    if (isChart) {
      console.log("CURSOR IS ON CHART");
    }
  }
});
```